# animation not occuring using jquery on local server

Tags: jquery, dom, settimeout, fadeout

I am using FF8 and CHROME Version 33.0.1750.154 m.
The problem i am facing is that i am not being able to hide a div with fade effect. I know questions have been asked earlier by others on this topic(I have even tried them out), but none of the solution worked for me.
I cannot understand where i am going wrong. The only thing that worked for me is the code stated above. But what i want is the fade effect.
Please point out my mistakes.

UPDATE: getting
     TypeError: $(...).fadeout is not a function

in firefox console using

```
 setTimeout(function(){$('#Layer4).fadeout(500);}4000);
```

please help.

```
    <html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#Layer4
{
background-color:#0099CC;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: `$(function(){// matter of DOM ready I suppose });`

Comment: @Amit Joki Yeah, I Initially tried using document.ready but with no use.

Comment: Did you try `$('#Layer4').fadeOut();`?

Comment: Yes you're missing DOM ready but after 4 seconds the dom is likely to be ready. Your link to jquery is most likely incorrect. Replace with a version from a CDN and see if it then works `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're simply not linking to jQuery properly. Try using the CDN resources, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
```

And then your fade function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#Layer4').fadeOut(500);
        },4000);
    });
</script>
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mtyAZ/

Comment: It should still be wrapped with `$(function(){});`

Comment: Absolutely. I was being lazy. Edited accordingly :)

Comment: @Popnoodles, i am using the application on a local server. Hence i donloaded version 1.10.4 and referenced the specified files but still not working.

Comment: @Ayan your references are wrong. You can still (and should) use cdn anyway.

Answer (score 0):

okay, finally solved the problem. The place where i was going wrong was i was using

```
 fadeout
```

instead of

```
 fadeOut
```

NOTE:i am still using local js files instead of direct links to CDN.
@Popnoodles, thanks for your replies and constant support.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#Layer4').hide(500);
  }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to avoid "try this" answers and post something you are confident works. It is also useful to explain the difference and why it now works.

Comment: After 4 seconds the dom is likely to be ready. While this is the correct way to use jQuery in the head of the document, it shouldn't necessarily fix the issue.